# SaxParse Exception Unexpected token

Tags: android

i have this code :

```
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
Utilities parser = new Utilities();


try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlfile));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(text.toString()));
    doc = db.parse(is);

} catch (IOException e) {

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}  catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and i'm getting this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT 030812Z_1_CDEE94...@1:60 in java.io.StringReader@4278b0f0)
```

does any one have any idea why i should get this error i'm running it on ICS and 4.1 and it works fine but with 4.2 i get this error

Comment: You can say `is.setCharacterStream(new FileReader(xmlfile))` and remove the StringBuilder, the BufferedReader, and the loop that reads the file.

Comment: Please post the XML file that you are reading.

Comment: here is the link of the xml data http://ph.adways.net/compact_news/api.php?category=Top
i try to make a file write the xml in sd card

Comment: i tried your suggestion but no luck. i try running it on android version 4.0 and 4.1 its working but when trying to run it in 4.2 i get the error what seems to be the problem?